# dont fetch data to dataTable in success function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable

I want to show the data received from the `getMember.php` file in the `myTable`. I used the following code but i don't see any data in the table.

PHP :

```
          <table class="table" id="myTable">                    
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>number</th>
                        <th>status</th>
                        <th>created</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

javascript :

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php_action/getMember.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {member_id : noVam},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
            $('#myTable').dataTable({
                data: response,
                serverside: true,
                columns: [{
                    'data': 'id'
                }, {
                    'data': 'noVam'
                }, {
                    'data': 'status'
                }, {
                    'data': 'created'
                }]
            });
            var count = Object.keys(response).length;

            $("#number").val(count);

        } // /success
    }); // /fetch selected member info
```

I want the `dataTable` commands to be in the `success function`

Comment: i feel you're doing it the other way around, use the data table ajax api, not using an ajax then instantiating the data table

Comment: @Kevin recognizes datatable but does not show a row in it